# Finding a csv file by traversing sub directories

Tags: python, file, path

I have a folder structure as below : Referring to the structure below, I am trying to access from the python file named 'MyFile.py', the csv file "sample4.csv" that is within the subdirectory "2021" (folder within 'yearlydata_subfolder2').

I've tried using os.path with the code below, but that doesn't seem to work and it returns 'FileNotFoundError'. Could someone please help?

```
C:.
├───1. Parent Folder : 
│       'Myfile.py'

   ├───2. 'data'  (subfolder1)

       ├───3. 'AWSyearly'                      (subfolder2)
           ├───3.1. '2020'                     (folder within 'yearlydata_subfolder2')
               sample1.csv                     (file in folder '2020')
               ├───3.1.1 monthlydata_2020      (subfolder within 2020)
                   sample2_2020_Jan.csv
                   sample3_2020_Feb.csv

           ├───3.2 '2021'                      (folder within 'yearlydata_subfolder2')
               sample4.csv                     (file in folder '2021') 
               ├───3.2.1 monthlydata_2021      (subfolder within 2021)
                   sample5_2021_Jan.csv
                   sample6_2021_Feb.csv
```

Code:

```
def access_csv():
    path = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),os.path.dirname(__file__)))
    print("Path of csv is:", path)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            if file.startswith('sample4') and file.endswith(".csv"):
                df = pd.read_csv(file, decimal=",", delimiter=";", index_col=0)
    return df
```

Comment: Is the printed path right?

Comment: Yes. It prints the correct path leading up to the 'Parent Folder' .

Comment: The "else" part of a for-loop will be executed if the loop is exhausted and wasn't exited with `break` beforehand. Therefore in your code it will be executed anyway. Better return the dataframe directly after loading it from the file and return the error message after the outer for-loop. The else-block can be omitted then.

Comment: Even after commenting out the else part, I get a 'FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:sample4.csv'

Comment: `files` only contains the filenames without paths. You must `os.path.join` the`root` and the `file`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html):

```py
import glob

parent_dir_fp = r"/parent_folder" # update this

matching_filepaths = glob.glob(parent_dir_fp + "/**/2021/sample4.csv", recursive=True)
# do whatever with filepaths from here
```